# How to determine what technology google used to build the website?

Tags: jquery, css, html, angularjs

Please tell me in which technology/program/language/code Google has built this website? [www.google.com/inbox](http://www.google.com/inbox)

I really like the interactivity/animation and I want to learn learn this. Please guide me so that I can go ahead in the right direction.

Great Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this amazing website that provides you all the info regarding technologies used by particular websites. Try it out http://builtwith.com/

Comment: This looks like a really nice tool.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know big parts of inbox were written with GWT.

http://www.gwtproject.org/